# Can I make React Native image slider "modal"style?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile

Can I do something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n00K0.png) using react native, and which packages should I use? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try to use the [react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal) npm package for opening modal and creating an image slider.